# Return multiple PostgreSQL values in table format

Tags: c#, postgresql, postgis

Pretty much stuck on this for the past few days. I wouldn't normally post here but what I'm trying to come up with just searching on my own doesn't work. I want to query PostgreSQL and come up with multiple records that each have multiple fields (indicated by my SELECT statement). Since I don't know the # of records returned I figured some sort of while loop was best. I just cant seem get all my values as a list and then throw that list into a table, adding rows as needed.

```
NpgsqlConnection pgconn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
pgconn.Open();

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT line, oper, subst_a, from_loc, to_loc, area " + 
                                          "FROM ab_basedata.superpipes_ihs " +
                                          "WHERE gdm_approv = '" + lic_num_lbl + "'", pgconn);

List<List<string>> pipes = new List<List<string>> { };
NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    pipes.Add("Line: " + dr.GetValue(0) + " " + dr.GetValue(1) + " " + dr.GetValue(2) + " " + dr.GetValue(3) + " " + dr.GetValue(4) + " " + dr.GetValue(5) + " Office");

    foreach (List<string> pip in pipes)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Text = string.Join(" ", pipes);
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        docTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try recoding the lines after you create the `command` like this...

```
List<List<string>> pipes = new List<List<string>>();
NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    List<string> pip = new List<string>();

    pip.Add("Line:");

    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
        pip.Add(dr.GetString(i));

    pip.Add("Office");

    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    cell1.Text = string.Join(" ", pip);
    row.Cells.Add(cell1);
    docTable.Rows.Add(row); 

    pipes.Add(pip);
}

// close DB resources if finished with them
dr.close();
pgconn.close();
```

I'm assuming here that you really do want to stuff all the data into one cell, rather than a cell for each item. If you don't need `pipes` elsewhere in your code, then it can be removed.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Although it doesn't look pretty, I might try some formatting or maybe break it up column wise, just not sure how in depth I want to get with this info since it's more of an after thought when the user pulls up pipeline information.